# Came VS have come, interchangeable here?

Tags: tense

> While some sand is formed in oceans from things like shells and rocks, most sand is made up of tiny bits of rock that **came** all the way from the mountains!

Can i use **have come** instead of **came** in this context?
To me,  it seems possible because for a long time the action was done not at a certain moment.
So, is there meaning difference between two of them?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Came** suggests that sometime in the past, the sand was in the mountains and then removed.

**Have come** suggests that the sand has come from the mountain at some recent point in time.

**Came** is the correct verb tense in this situation, unless you know at which specific point in time the sand came from the mountain.